# makefile substitution not working like expected

Tags: c, makefile, substitution

I have the following makefile:

```
C_FILES_CLNT = add_clnt.c, add_client.c, initfunction.c, add_xdr.c
O_FILES_CLNT = $(C_FILES_CLNT:%.c=%.o)

all:
    echo $(O_FILES_CLNT)
```

and I would expect that all the `O_FILE_CLNT` are .o-Files. But sadly the output is:

```
add_clnt.c, add_client.c, initfunction.c, add_xdr.o
```

so only the last file is a .o-File. I took this example straight out of a example-makefile. 
Can somebody explain, why all `O_FILE_CLNT` are not .o-Files ?

Gruß, Andre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word separator isn't the comma `,` but the white space . So changing the first variable to:

```
C_FILES_CLNT = add_clnt.c add_client.c initfunction.c add_xdr.c
```

should make it work.

Comment: Np, be sure to accept the answer :) I've edited it to specify word separator.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to above answer

`so only the last file is a .o-File`

Its because only last file name has the extension `.c` rest of the files are treated as `.c,` extension that is why they are not taken by the rule `%.c=%.o`

You can experiment around to see how makefile is working, for example change `O_FILES_CLNT = $(C_FILES_CLNT:%.c=%.o)` to `O_FILES_CLNT = $(C_FILES_CLNT:%.c,=%.o)` (observe `,` in `%c,`) then all the file names will be converted to `.o` except the last one :P

Conclusion: Makefile treats space as a word seperator not comma. The same rule applies to compilers also where we give flags speperated by spaces.